# Defining a recursive function (structural induction)

Tags: logic, solution-verification, induction, programming

> A list of integers can be recursively defined as follows:
>
> ```
> <IntList> ::= [] | cons(<Int>, <IntList>)
> ```
>
> Write a recursive function named `allEqualTo` that takes an integer and a list as input, and
> returns `1` if all the numbers in the list are equal to the given integer, and `0` otherwise. For example,
> `allEqualTo(5, cons(5, cons(5, [])))` should return `1`, and `allEqualTo(5, cons(5, cons(3, cons(5, []))))` should return `0`.
>
> NOTE: Write a function, not a Prolog predicate or code in any other language. Feel free to use pattern matching.

This is what I did and when I checked answers, they did it in a totally different way, but I am still not convinced this is wrong, so I’m asking here.

```
allEqualTo(x, []) = 0
allEqualTo(x, cons(x, [])) = 1
allEqualTo(x, cons(y, a)) = 0
allEqualTo(x, cons(x, a)) = cons(x, allEqualTo(x, cons(x, a))
```

Edit: The solution looks like:

```
allEqualTo(x, []) = 0
allEqualTo(x, cons(x, [])) = 1
allEqualTo(x, cons(y, a)) = 0 x≠y 
allEqualTo(x, cons(x, a)) = allEqualTo(x, L)
```

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with that programing language, and I transcripted the image, but it seems there is a closing parenthesis missing at your last instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but as stated in the question I'm not allowed to write a programming function rather a logical one (mathematics) as this is a course in logic (programming + maths). But do you think this question belongs here in stackexchange or should I post it somewhere else?

Comment: I think the question is better suited for Code Review, Stack Overflow, perhaps even Math Overflow or Code Golf, but I have no experience on those forums.

Comment: Indeed the answer you've given looks more like a code snippet than a math or logic function.  I can write an answer as a math or logic function, but unfortunately it's likely the question will be deleted as off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The last case of your function doesn't type: you are returning a list (with both an integer and booleans ---morally speaking) but `allEqualTo` returns an integer.
- `allEqualTo(x,[])` should equal 1: indeed every element in the list is equal to `x`.
- I'm going to write `cons` with infix notation `cons(x,xs) ≡ x :: xs`.
- I don't know the details of the syntax of your language (you didn't provide one) but you should be able to translate anything I write.

---

Consider functions `and : Int → Int → Int` and infix `(==) : Int → Int → Int` that behave like their corresponding bool-valued versions but with `0` instead of `False` and `1` instead of `True`.

Given an integer `x` and a list `a :: b :: c :: []` you want to return `1` if `a` = `b` = `c` = `x` and `0` otherwise.

Notice that if you map the `[]` to `1` and the `(::)` to the function `λy,b. x == y and b`, you would map the last list to the int

```
x == a and (x == b and (x == c and 1))
```

which is what we want. If you have a `fold` implemented
you can write up to currying

```
allEqualTo x := fold 1 (λy,b. x == y and b)
```

where `fold : ∀a,b. b → (a → b → b) → [a] → b`.

---

If you want a construction with pattern matching you can unfold this definition (up to currying) to get

```
allEqualTo(x, [])    = 1
allEqualTo(x, y::xs) = x == y and allEqualTo(x, xs)
```

---

Notice here it's key that `allEqualTo(x, []) = 1` since otherwise when you get to the end of the list you'll always return `0`.

Also this maps the unit of the list to the ("multiplicative" -- `and`) unit of the booleans, and since it's the `and` what you are using for the recursive case, this makes your `allEqualTo` an algebra morphism. Doing otherwise would be unnatural.

[Here's a nice introduction to the topic of $F$-algebras.](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/28/f-algebras/) Although it might require some extra reading beforehand.

Ask anything, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this, it was a little hard to understand considering different notations but I sort of understood what you are saying. But I provided the actual solutions if you check edits. So I see that my function is wrong because I am putting a function inside a list definition, is that even possible as in my definition should just cause some sort of error.